# Favicon not showing when I send the link in a text message, WhatsApp, iMessage, etc

Tags: favicon, http-status-code-401

I have a site in webflow. I password protected the entire site. Webflow redirects you to the 401 page to enter the password.

The problem is when I text someone the link it shows as a broken or invalid link resulting in my favicon not showing with the link.

When you click the link it actually works but it reads as a /401 page instead of the homepage. Im trying to avoid creating my own password protection when webflow has it already built.

I attached a screenshot below showing me text my link to myself then I resent it after I removed the password protection and my favicon showed up.

[image: screenshot]